# How to use if ($(this).val() == "id1"|| $(this).val() == "id2") with SQL DB return?

Tags: javascript, sql-server

Using a .change function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#id_product").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "id1"
  || $(this).val() == "id2"
  ...
  ) {
    $('#Div').show();
    $('#Label').show();
  } else {
    $('#Div').hide();
    $('#Label').hide();
  }
});
$("#id_product").trigger("change");
</script>
```

which works fine, how should i proceed to get id1, id2 etc... from an SQL request instead of having them typed in javascript ?

SQL Server request:

```sql
SELECT [scd_name],[id_pole],[id_scd]
  FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[scd]
```

This works fine and return me the desired values in column id_scd.

Thanks ;-)

Comment: That depends on when/how that data is available to you.  Are you dynamically generating this page in a server-side application which can inject those values?  Do you need to make an AJAX request to fetch those values?  Something else?